# Publish Self-Contained .Net Core Windows Forms application into a single File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to publish a self-Contained .Net Core Windows Forms application into a single .exe file so that computers that don't have the runtime environment can launch my application. I'm publishing the application for windows 7 with the following CMD commands.

Build:
`dotnet build -r win7-x64`
Publish:
`dotnet publish -r win7-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained`

After doing this, when I run the .exe file on a windows 7 device nothing opens. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: 1) Test without PublishSingleFile and see what happens. 2) Windows 7 is end of life, so even if you hit a bug no one is going to fix it.